# Como obtener el listado de clientes con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que necesito crear en base al autocomplete es esto:

1- Crear función que al ingresar un texto por parametro, llame al servicio de obtener clientes con ese dato y llene las opciones de customerSearchInput.

---

2- Bindear chzn key up para actualizar listado (usar `$(document).on('keyup', selector, funtcion () { ... })` llamando a la función del paso 1

---

3- Funcion del paso 2, agregar
a - longitud mínima requerida para llamar al paso 1
b - Comportamiento de timeout para poder hacer delay para que el usuario ingrese más caracteres antes de llamar a la función del paso 1

---

Lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
var timeOut = null;
var enabledTrigger = true;

$(document).on('keyup','#customerSearchInput_chzn input', function () {
    if(!enabledTrigger) return;

    enabledTrigger = false;
    setTimeout(function() { enabledTrigger = true}, 2000);
    if(this.value.length > 1)
        customersToAutocompleteFiltered(this.value);
});
```

y esta es la función que tendría que ordenar en base a lo que agregué para completar el proceso

```
var customersToAutocompleteFiltered = function() {
    $.getJSON('/sales/ajaxGetAllCustomers', function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            $('#customerSearchInput').html('<option></option>');
            $('#customerSearchInput').append('<option style="display:none" value="-1"></option>');
            $(data.customers).each(function(idx, element) {
                $('#customerSearchInput')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", element.id)
                        .text((element.surname != '' ? element.name + ' ' + element.surname : element.name)));

            });
            $('#customerSearchInput').trigger('liszt:updated');
            if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿y tu duda/problema es?

Comment: como hacer en la ultima funcion para agregar un parámetro string por el cual buscar, y como pasarselo al servicio de obtener clientes seria mi duda para completar la funcion

Comment: entre la url y el function(data) debes pasar los valores en formato {clave: "valor", clave2: "valor2"} https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!